# Sum in crystal report accordind to field data?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

i want to make formula field in crystal report
i want

> sum of amount where Voucher type is =="CR" and "BR" and "PR"

How i make it in crystal report i dnt have any idea

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why create a formula when you can just create a summary field by selecting your column and going to the menu and selecting Insert Summary, Insert Subtotal or Insert Grand Total depending on your needs? You can place the summary field in a group section as a subtotal, or in the report footer as a grand total.

If you need to apply a conversion in the formula, you can use CCur like this:

```
sum( CCur({ MycolumnName}) )
```

More information on converting types in Crystal Reports can be found here [1](http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Chapter06_XI.asp).